# kafka connectors - getting started - could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Hi I am following a tutorial (not sure if I can post link here) to learn kafka connect

I have downloaded confluent-6.2.0

I run this command

`bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties`

and get the following message

```
could not find or load main class org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone
```

I print out the classpath it is

`$DIR/share/java/confluent-security/connect/*:$DIR/share/java/kafka/*:$DIR/share/java/confluent-common/*:$DIR//share/java/kafka-serde-tools/*:$DIR/share/java/monitoring-interception/*`

I have checked the class ConnectStandalone is in
`$DIR/share/java/kafka/connect-runtime-6.2.0-ce.jar`

Wonder if anything I have missed?

`$DIR` is the directory is the root directory of confluent

This is the plugin path in my `etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties` file

`plugin.path=/d/developer/confluent/confluent-6.2.1/share/java`

This is the content of the directory

```
λ ls /d/developer/confluent/confluent-6.2.1/share/java

acl/                       confluent-hub-client/        kafka/                     monitoring-interceptors/
ce-kafka-http-server/      confluent-kafka-mqtt/        kafka-connect-replicator/  rest-utils/
ce-kafka-rest-extensions/  confluent-metadata-service/  kafka-rest-bin/            schema-registry/
ce-kafka-rest-servlet/     confluent-rebalancer/        kafka-rest-lib/
confluent-common/          confluent-security/          kafka-serde-tools/
confluent-control-center/  confluent-telemetry/         ksqldb/
```

Comment: The share/java folder should already be on the classpath, so you don't need to make this your plugin folder. (However, that is unrelated to the error). What shell are you using? WSL2? Have you tried running Kafka Connect in Docker so that we can actually reproduce the issue using a similar environment?

Comment: Running directly on windows via cmder

I will try docker or wsl2

Comment: The new Windows 10 Terminal app basically makes ConEmu pointless as it can open Linux, Powershell and CMD sessions on its own. But, yes, Confluent Platform doesn't support Windows

Answer (score 0):

I have docker container for an Kafka-kenises application which in turn calls following class

`<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone"/>`

though I got error as follows, I am newbie to docker, Kafka and Kinesis, any idea what this error is and how to fix it?

```
 task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
10
  value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
9
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneConfig)
8
[2022-10-10 17:41:33,984] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
7
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/record/InvalidRecordException
6
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:81)
5
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException
4
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
3
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
2
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
```